# Cassegrain telescope design

Tags: astronomy, telescopes

How are the dimensions of a cassegrain telescope configured? In particular the distance of the secondary hyperbolic mirror from the primary mirror and also the diameter of the secondary mirror. Any equations or diagrams will be a massive help.

I also read that the back focus of the hyperbolic secondary mirror must coincide with focus of the primary. Why is this necessary?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassegrain_reflector

Comment: for performance and design details see Imbriale: Large Antennas of the Deep Space Network, Wiley-Interscience 2003; you may also get the manuscript from JPL's website